# Show login screen If the user is not logged in | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, window.location

I try to display Login Screen in the spesific URL `('ads/audience-insights')` If the user is not logged in. but no luck.

Can you correct my code? what's wrong?

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('ads/audience-insights') != -1) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("cnt9", function(result) {
        if (result.cnt9 == null || result.cnt9 == -1 || result.cnt9 >= 40) {
            // show login screen
            showLoginScreen();
        }
    });
}
```

---

This code == user Not logged in yet..

> `result.cnt9 == null || result.cnt9 == -1 || result.cnt9 >= 40`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `chrome.storage` or the callback function.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  var a = localStorage.cnt9;
  if (a == null || a == -1 || a >= 40)
    alert("Not Logged In!");
}
```

You also do not have to check if the user is on a specific page as the code will not execute if they are not on said page in the first place.